# Sorting card information algorithm PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a 'problem'/ think of an algorithm and would like some feedback as to whether I am thinking in the right direction or not.

Let's say I have a stack of boarding cards. On each card there is one departure point, and one arrival point. I don't know what my starting and ending point of my journey is. All I have is this stack of boarding cards, which I should sort and then return correct the travel advice. So I am thinking:

I am going to put all of my information in a simple csv file, all of my departures in column 1, and all of my arrivals in column 2. Other information such as gates and seat numbers don't matter just yet for the sorting process. If I want to find out what my starting point is, all I have to do is loop through the first column and check to see if there is an arrival point that doesn't exist in the departure column also. That is going to be my starting point. I am thinking, in order to find out the rest of the trip (3 more destinations) I'd have to do basically the same thing, with some sort of nested for loop to figure out my next step.

What do you guys think? Is there an easier way to do this? Sorry if my story is not very clear.

Comment: If the stack of cards represents a contiguous travel from A to B (where A and B are different) without loops then you can find A as the departure that is not in arrived to on any card. As soon as you know the A - you can build the whole route. Just follow the A->X arrival and so on.

Comment: There are many [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) for this already.

Comment: Right :-) thanks for clearing it up. Not sure why people are down voting my question, perhaps it was stupid. I am new to this and trying to find my way. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Don't take the down-votes personally. The question is broad and somewhat opinion based, which is not considered a good question on SO.

Comment: Awh okay I get it :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable simple approach.

More theoretically, what you're describing sounds like a sort over a set of elements which have only a [partial ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (as opposed to most sorting algorithms, which assume a [total ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)). You might look into [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).